# Need advise generating data-tables

Tags: php, sql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Working in Zend framework and using Doctrine.

I have 1 competition, concisting of several matches ( could be from as little as 4 up to as much as 50 ).
These matches usually have the same players in them.

I have the tables:
Competitions
Matches
Matchresults
Users

First step, get all matches belong to competition, this is easy, so no worries there.
Now it gets tricky:
Step two, get all results of said matches, still ok, i can get the data, but presenting this data is the challenging part.
Step three, get the names from the users table, where the users id is equal to the users id given in the matchresults table.

The end result should be a table looking something like this.

```
Name                   Match1   match2  match3 total points
firstname + lastname   50       60      61     171
firstname + lastname   52       56      66     174
```

I can get all the data correctly, but getting it all in the right field is a bit of a problem.
Could anyone point me in the right direction or maybe give me an example?

Cheers,

Mark

EDIT: clarification.
This is for a fishing competition.
Each match has an x amount of fisherman and these get points according to what they catch.
The calender year has been divided into competitions, 2 or 4, can be different each year.
These matches have a begin-date and an end-date and all matches that have been played in between the begin date and end date of a competition, belong to that competition.

Now the user of the app, wants to make an excell export, showing all the results in the manner i've shown above, the more matches, the more columns with points in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make yourself a function which transforms a competition into a list of users along with their results.  Something like:

```
public function transform($competition)
{
    $users = array();

    $matches = $competition->getMatches();
    $matchCount = count($matches);
    $matchNum = 0;

    foreach($matches as $match)
    {
        $matchNum++;
        foreach($match->getResults() as $result)
        {
            $user = $result->getUser();
            $userId = $user->getId();

            // Add new user if necessary
            if (!isset($users[$userId]))
            {
                // Store the name
                $users[$userId]['name'] = $user->getFirstName() . ' ' . $user->getLastName();

                // Spot to store total points
                $users[$userId]['total'] = null;

                // Individual match results
                $users[$userId]['matches'] = array();

                // Spots for each match in case users skip a match
                for($i = 1; $i <= $matchCount; $i++) $users[$userId]['matches']['Match' . $i] = null;

            }
            $points = $result->getPoints();
            $users[$userId]['matches']['Match' . $matchNum] = $points;
            $users[$userId]['total'] += $points;
        }
    }
    // Use usort if you want to sort by names

    // Done
    var_dump($users);
    return $users;
}
```